Suggested approach to distinguish between noun and verb (with example)
I found the meaning of the word credential:
something that gives a title to credit or confidence
But I am still confused what role credit has. Is it noun or verb?
How to deal in similar situations to distinguish noun and verb?

It's the same POS as confidence. Why do you think it should be a verb?

It is a rather opaque definition (what does "give a title" mean? What sort of title? Which of the several meanings of credit are implied?). Asking for an explanation wouldn't be unreasonable, but it's obvious that "credit" is a noun, it's just less obvious what's going on in the rest of the phrase.

@user405662 I thought that it can be the same pos as confidence but probably I have gaps in grammar and luck confidence.

@stuart-f Yes. Definition is not clear. Thanks.

Here's M-W's definition of credential as an adjective and a noun:

adjective
: warranting c̲r̲e̲d̲i̲t̲ or confidence 
noun
1 : something that gives a title to c̲r̲e̲d̲i̲t̲ or confidence
2 credentials plural : testimonials or certified documents showing that a person is entitled to c̲r̲e̲d̲i̲t̲ or has a right to exercise official power
3 : certificate, diploma

(Underlines mine.)
Firstly, from the adjective definition, it's indisputable that credit and confidence are in coordination, and therefore that credit is a noun in the first noun definition just as it is in the adjective definition. This is because the meaning of noun credential is closely related to that of adjective credential.
Secondly, from the second noun definition, which says in part a person is entitled to credit, credit has to be a noun. And this part means "a person is given a title to credit".
Last but not least, the first noun definition should be parsed like this:

something that [VP gives [NP a title to [NP-coordination credit or confidence]]]

Regarding @LPH's answer, which the OP has already accepted as the best answer, I don't quite understand what it should mean to "credit a title" in context. The only context I can think of that might use the concept of "credit a title" is when you take out a loan that uses as collateral an asset to which the borrower has a title.

"Credit a title" : this  is not correct without a complement; the construction where "credit" can be understood as "believe" is "credit sth/sb as sth or A with B". Consequently, you can disregard that, and delete your comment  if you think it unduly clutters your answer.

Hmm but then what does it mean to give a title to confidence? What does it mean to be entitled to confidence? Is either of those really standard English?

@Cerberus-ReinstateMonica I take it to mean that the credential gives the bearer a justifiable reason to be viewed with confidence by others.

@JK2: I don't know, but that sounds a bit odd to me.

Consider
The old man the boats.
The horse raced past the barn fell.
The complex houses soldiers' families.
The above are understood as
The elderly form the crew of the boats Verb = "to man" to supply labour [for something]
The horse that was raced past the barn fell down -> reduced relative clause
The complex provides housing for the families of soldiers Verb = to house - to provide accommodation for something or someone
There is no easy solution to understanding any of the original sentences. The only approach is to alter the cadence in the hopes that the sentence becomes comprehensible.
The other piece of guidance is "Don't write such sentences."

I got this point and will use it.

But the OP's example (M-W definition) is not like your examples.  It's straightforwardly a noun.

Great examples, @Greybeard. But how are they germane to the question?

They are germane in that they provide examples of  noun-verb confusion and provide real sentences to which the OP can apply my suggestions regarding the cadence (and tone).
